# Insertar registros con select en insert

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy intentado insertar registros en una tabla `TB_DET_SUSCRIPCION_DOC` pero el `SELECT` devuelve mas de un registro.

el error es el siguiente.

> Informe de error: Error SQL: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns
>   more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

La consulta:

```
INSERT INTO cuentas.TB_DET_SUSCRIPCION_DOC (id_det_suscripcion_doc, id_suscripcion_doc, id_tip_producto, rango_envio) 
VALUES (SQ_DET_SUSCRIPCION_DOC.NextVal,(SELECT cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.id_suscripcion_doc 
FROM cuentas.TB_SUSCRIPCION_DOC WHERE TRUNC(fec_inicio_envio,'DD') BETWEEN to_date('01-07-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND to_date('31-07-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
AND cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.id_tip_doc_susc = 23 
AND cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.fec_termino_envio is null), 0,0);
```

Alguno ha tenido ese problema? me puede decir como lo soluciono?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La construcción que utilizas:

insert into Tabla (Campos)
  values (x, y);

Sirve para insertar un solo registro.

Tu problema, como lo dice claramente el mensaje de error, es que la sub-consulta que ejecutas devuelve más de un registro y ante tal caso, Oracle no sabría cuál de esos registros es relevante, y por ello devuelve el error.

Tu caso tiene dos posibles soluciones:

### Que la sub-consulta devuelva un solo registro

Dado que hay varios, afina a más la clausula where para que devuelva uno solo. Si es correcto que devuelva varios y es arbitraria la decisón, tienes formas de forzar al motor a devolver un solo registro, por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO cuentas.TB_DET_SUSCRIPCION_DOC (
    id_det_suscripcion_doc
  , id_suscripcion_doc
  , id_tip_producto
  , rango_envio
) 
VALUES (
    SQ_DET_SUSCRIPCION_DOC.NextVal
  , (SELECT cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.id_suscripcion_doc 
       FROM cuentas.TB_SUSCRIPCION_DOC 
      WHERE TRUNC(fec_inicio_envio,'DD') BETWEEN to_date('01-07-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND to_date('31-07-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
        AND cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.id_tip_doc_susc = 23 
        AND cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.fec_termino_envio is null)
        and ROWNUM = 1
  , 0
  , 0);
```

### Inserta todos los valores devueltos

Si, por el contrario, la sentencia es correcta y lo que quieres es insertar un registro por cada valor devuelto, cambia la construcción a un `insert`/`select`, así:

```
INSERT INTO cuentas.TB_DET_SUSCRIPCION_DOC (
    id_det_suscripcion_doc
  , id_suscripcion_doc
  , id_tip_producto
  , rango_envio
) 
SELECT   SQ_DET_SUSCRIPCION_DOC.NextVal 
       , cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.id_suscripcion_doc 
       , 0
       , 0
  FROM cuentas.TB_SUSCRIPCION_DOC 
 WHERE TRUNC(fec_inicio_envio,'DD') BETWEEN to_date('01-07-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND to_date('31-07-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
   AND cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.id_tip_doc_susc = 23 
   AND cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.fec_termino_envio is null);
```

Esta construcción insertará tantas filas como devuelva la consulta.

Comment: gracias por la explicación !

Comment: ¡Un placer! Me alegra ser de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Usa los valores estáticos como parte del select en columnas falsa

```
INSERT INTO cuentas.TB_DET_SUSCRIPCION_DOC (id_det_suscripcion_doc, id_suscripcion_doc, id_tip_producto, rango_envio) 
SELECT SQ_DET_SUSCRIPCION_DOC.NextVal,cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.id_suscripcion_doc
, 0,0 
FROM cuentas.TB_SUSCRIPCION_DOC WHERE TRUNC(fec_inicio_envio,'DD') BETWEEN to_date('01-07-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND to_date('31-07-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
AND cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.id_tip_doc_susc = 23 
AND cuentas.tb_suscripcion_doc.fec_termino_envio is null;
```

Comment: Independiente que la secuencia y los datos 0, 0. que quiero agregar no pertenezcan al select ?, es posible que se produzca alguna inconsistencia con los datos cuando se inserte??

Comment: Tu respuesta era la esperada pero faltaba la explicación que @jachguate gracias por contestar

Comment: gracias por la observación